# How to convert array of object to XML format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I am working on node project. I got a requirement like i have array of object data, i have to convert that to xml format. i tried with **json2xml libray**. i converted but it is created only **single Agent Tag**.

In side the agents tag i need separate agent including refURL for each agent tag

each **agent** Tag should have **refurl,agentID,firstName,lastName, userName** **agent**, but the converted xml is combining all **refurl,agentID,firstName,lastName, userName** is single **agent** tag

```
    {
    "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5022",
    "changeStamp": 12,
    "agentCount": 7,
    "description": "Cumulus Outbound Team",
    "name": "CumulusOutbound",
    "peripheral": {
        "id": 5000,
        "name": "CUCM_PG_1"
    },
    "peripheralId": 5000,
    "supervisorCount": 1,
    "agents": [{
        "agent": [{
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5197",
            "agentId": "1085",
            "firstName": "Owen",
            "lastName": "Harvey",
            "userName": "oharvey"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5201",
            "agentId": "1320",
            "firstName": "Bruce",
            "lastName": "Wayne",
            "userName": "bwayne"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5202",
            "agentId": "1321",
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Parker",
            "userName": "pparker"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5203",
            "agentId": "1322",
            "firstName": "Tony",
            "lastName": "Stark",
            "userName": "tstark"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5204",
            "agentId": "1323",
            "firstName": "Steve",
            "lastName": "Rogers",
            "userName": "srogers"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5205",
            "agentId": "1324",
            "firstName": "Bruce",
            "lastName": "Banner",
            "userName": "bbanner"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5231",
            "agentId": "1086",
            "firstName": "Annika",
            "lastName": "Hamilton",
            "userName": "annika"
        }, {
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5118",
            "agentId": "1317",
            "firstName": "Donald",
            "lastName": "Duckling",
            "userName": "dduck"
        }]
    }],
    "supervisors": [{
        "supervisor": [{
            "refURL": "/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5174",
            "agentId": "1082",
            "firstName": "Rick",
            "lastName": "Barrows",
            "userName": "rbarrows@dcloud.cisco.com"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Actually it should be like below

```
<agentTeam>
   <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5022</refURL>
   <changeStamp>12</changeStamp>
   <agentCount>7</agentCount>
   <description>Cumulus Outbound Team</description>
   <name>CumulusOutbound</name>
   <peripheral>
      <id>5000</id>
      <name>CUCM_PG_1</name>
   </peripheral>
   <peripheralId>5000</peripheralId>
   <supervisorCount>1</supervisorCount>
   <agents>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5197</refURL>
         <agentId>1085</agentId>
         <firstName>Owen</firstName>
         <lastName>Harvey</lastName>
         <userName>oharvey</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5201</refURL>
         <agentId>1320</agentId>
         <firstName>Bruce</firstName>
         <lastName>Wayne</lastName>
         <userName>bwayne</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5202</refURL>
         <agentId>1321</agentId>
         <firstName>Peter</firstName>
         <lastName>Parker</lastName>
         <userName>pparker</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5203</refURL>
         <agentId>1322</agentId>
         <firstName>Tony</firstName>
         <lastName>Stark</lastName>
         <userName>tstark</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5204</refURL>
         <agentId>1323</agentId>
         <firstName>Steve</firstName>
         <lastName>Rogers</lastName>
         <userName>srogers</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5205</refURL>
         <agentId>1324</agentId>
         <firstName>Bruce</firstName>
         <lastName>Banner</lastName>
         <userName>bbanner</userName>
      </agent>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5231</refURL>
         <agentId>1086</agentId>
         <firstName>Annika</firstName>
         <lastName>Hamilton</lastName>
         <userName>annika</userName>
      </agent>
   </agents>
   <supervisors>
      <supervisor>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5174</refURL>
         <agentId>1082</agentId>
         <firstName>Rick</firstName>
         <lastName>Barrows</lastName>
         <userName>rbarrows@dcloud.cisco.com</userName>
      </supervisor>
   </supervisors>
</agentTeam>
```

But it is converted like below

```
<agentTeam>
   <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5018</refURL>
   <changeStamp>9</changeStamp>
   <agentCount>4</agentCount>
   <description>Cumulus City Team</description>
   <name>CumulusCity</name>
   <peripheral>
      <id>5000</id>
      <name>CUCM_PG_1</name>
   </peripheral>
   <peripheralId>5000</peripheralId>
   <supervisorCount>1</supervisorCount>
   <agents>
      <agent>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5113</refURL>
         <agentId>1312</agentId>
         <firstName>John</firstName>
         <lastName>Elway</lastName>
         <userName>jelway</userName>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5118</refURL>
         <agentId>1317</agentId>
         <firstName>Donald</firstName>
         <lastName>Duck</lastName>
         <userName>dduck</userName>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5119</refURL>
         <agentId>1318</agentId>
         <firstName>Elmer</firstName>
         <lastName>Fudd</lastName>
         <userName>efudd</userName>
      </agent>
   </agents>
   <supervisors>
      <supervisor>
         <refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5174</refURL>
         <agentId>1082</agentId>
         <firstName>Rick</firstName>
         <lastName>Barrows</lastName>
         <userName>rbarrows@dcloud.cisco.com</userName>
      </supervisor>
   </supervisors>
</agentTeam>
```

Comment: Is the only difference between what you want and what you get with json2xml the line breaks ? In which case can't you just add them, maybe with a regex ? (or maybe just replace() depending on what you want)

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide sample code on how you're using the library? Your input and output structures appear to differ quite a lot, I have the impression that you  need to create an intermediate JSON string with the desired format.

Comment: no, the created XML with library is <agents><agent><refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5113</refURL><agentId>1312</agentId><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Elway</lastName><userName>jelway</userName><refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5118</refURL><agentId>1317</agentId><firstName>Donald</firstName><lastName>Duck</lastName><userName>dduck</userName><refURL>/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5119</refURL><agentId>1318</agentId><firstName>Elmer</firstName><lastName>Fudd</lastName><userName>efudd</userName></agent></agents> in this only one <agent> is created

Comment: each <agent> should have refurl,agentID,firstName,lastName, userName</agent> but the converted xml is combining all refurl,agentID,firstName,lastName, userName is single <agent> tag

Comment: You need to fix the json as the schema is incorrect for the expected output, i.e., "agent" is an array.  And it would be best to fix this at the source, such as the server that generates the json.

Comment: @Yogi, i cant fix JSON schema, because am getting this from another api response

Answer (score 2):

**Transform the json before conversion**

As noted in comments, the problem is with the json schema. Specifically the agent property is an array of one item whereas it should be an array of agents.  If you can't fix this problem at the json source then you will need to transform the data before feeding it to the json2xml converter.

And I think this can be done with a simple [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so:

```
data.agents = data.agents[0].agent.map(agent => ({agent: agent}));
```

**Update**

In response to OP's comment, the snippet was updated to display all the data rather than only what was changed.

**Snippet**

Run the snippet to see the result.

```js
const data = {"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agentteam/5022","changeStamp":12,"agentCount":7,"description":"Cumulus Outbound Team","name":"CumulusOutbound","peripheral":{"id":5000,"name":"CUCM_PG_1"},"peripheralId":5000,"supervisorCount":1,"agents":[{"agent":[{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5197","agentId":"1085","firstName":"Owen","lastName":"Harvey","userName":"oharvey"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5201","agentId":"1320","firstName":"Bruce","lastName":"Wayne","userName":"bwayne"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5202","agentId":"1321","firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Parker","userName":"pparker"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5203","agentId":"1322","firstName":"Tony","lastName":"Stark","userName":"tstark"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5204","agentId":"1323","firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Rogers","userName":"srogers"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5205","agentId":"1324","firstName":"Bruce","lastName":"Banner","userName":"bbanner"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5231","agentId":"1086","firstName":"Annika","lastName":"Hamilton","userName":"annika"},{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5118","agentId":"1317","firstName":"Donald","lastName":"Duckling","userName":"dduck"}]}],"supervisors":[{"supervisor":[{"refURL":"/unifiedconfig/config/agent/5174","agentId":"1082","firstName":"Rick","lastName":"Barrows","userName":"rbarrows@dcloud.cisco.com"}]}]}

before.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, " ");

data.agents = data.agents[0].agent.map(agent => ({agent: agent}));

after.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,null," ");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
textarea {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div>Original Data:</div>
    <pre id="before"></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div>Transformed Data:</div>
    <pre id="after"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ... nice answer, nice example code.

Comment: @yogi, that works for me. Thanks...! but how to add this complete converted agents to original JSON?

Comment: @PeterSeliger, do u have any idea how to add this completely converted agents data to original json data?

Comment: @GaneshPutta - The code already replaces agents in the original with the transformed version.  I've updated the code snippet to make that more clear.  Simply insert the transform code (mapping) where you pull data from the api.